# how do I make a alternative to google recapture without google or wordpress?

Tags: php, forms, validation

How do I make a alternative to google recapture without google or wordpress?

I want to use pure php if possible and dont know how, I tried using google Recapture and that dont work no matter how many times I try, and cant find any alternatives for free I have looked on codepen and google and duck and go and stack overflow, please help someone!
I would like it to look like google recapture v3 without using google.

I have tried all 3 versions and it don't work right, it either submits without a check or it sais wrong code even though the code is correct.

Comment: Software recommendations are off-topic on Stack Overflow. You can try [Software Recommendations SE.](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Are you looking for a solution like hCaptcha, or are you looking to program your own?

Comment: h crapture charges money i need open source / free!!! and i dint want to rely on a 3rd part every form submission i also want to learn thats what this site is supposed to be for, learning.

Comment: Yes looking to make my own and dont know how!

Comment: Simple one: `SPAMBOT question: What is six plus three?` generate random numbers in words each time. Correct answer: `Nine`

Comment: Or: `What is the name of this site?`

Comment: bots can get around math problems i want a graphical puzzle style one but no idea how to do it. or maybe some kind of slider / drag and drop obstical.

Comment: OK. In a hidden directory, store images with hashes of descriptions. Show a random image and ask for a description. Hash it, verify it.

Comment: and il send you email with my site link.

Comment: Well, I don't know how Google does it, but you can store images of cars and images with no cars, each labelled TRUE or FALSE. Ask the user to check boxes to determine which have cars.

Comment: Such as phpBB Community's challenge? You have to slide materials into two columns: OBJECTS and NON OBJECTS.

Comment: do you know how to do that?

Comment: im also using words to determine spam in this post please help if you can https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68898395/anti-spam-detection-in-php-getting-blank-pages-how-can-i-get-this-to-work